# Spring Boot Thymeleaf errors only when running on external Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, thymeleaf

I am developing a spring boot web app using thymeleaf as template engine.

When I leave a tag unclosed (like meta, link, br, hr or input tags) in my html templates, thymeleaf does not complain when running on the embedded spring boot tomcat (running the jar file).

But when I deploy the app to external stand alone tomcat (building a war artifact) I am getting thymeleaf parsing exceptions because of those unclosed tags.

I have also noticed that I do need the thymeleaf-layout-dialect dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

to compile when using the embedded tomcat but it compiles and runs fine without it when deployed to external stand alone tomcat.

Why is this happening? How can I fix it so it is the same both on the embedded tomcat as well as to any stand alone tomcat installation?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the problem with the exceptions thrown because of the unclosed tags using Neko HTML but I still haven't found out why these exceptions are thrown only when spring boot runs on an external tomcat and not when it runs using it's embedded tomcat.

Here is what I have done:

Set the property "spring.thymeleaf.mode" to "LEGACYHTML5".

```
spring.thymeleaf.mode=LEGACYHTML5
```

And in the pom.xml, add the dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.nekohtml</groupId>
    <artifactId>nekohtml</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.22</version>
</dependency>
```